# grep a file process the output to variable

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file with under 200 entries, they are not really uniform but with a grep before and after command I can get client data. Here is what the output of the command
`grep -i -b -A4 " Type      : Client" sample.txt`

```
Index     : 11
Type      : Client, Disk Proxy Client
Location  : 192.1680.11
Up Time   : 0d 0h 25m
Revision  : 6.3.1

Index     : 12
Type      : Client
Location  : 192.1680.12
Up Time   : 0d 0h 25m
Revision  : 7.0.1

Index     : 56
Type      : Client
Location  : 10.0.10.112
Up Time   : 0d 0h 25m
Revision  : 5.3.1
```

I want to run a while/for loop and separate each line into a variable to then push these values to database.

As a sample of getting I can get the "Location" for each grep result I can use this. I would like to put this in a script and grab all the output in to individual variables.
`cat sample.txt |grep -i -b -A4 "Type" |while read client; do echo "$client" |grep Location |awk '{print $4}'; done`

```
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
10.0.10.112
```

But if I try to put the same command into a multi-line script it gets processed as individual lines.
I would like to do more grep/sed..etc to get

```
index=11
type=client
location=192.168.0.11
```

fake sql query
sql -update .... $index,$type,$location

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Why is `location=192.1` and not `192.1680.11`? And why is the `type=client` ?

Comment: Try something like `awk '^Index/ {index=$3} /^Type/ {type=$3} /Location/ {location="unclear requirement"} /Revision/ { print index, type, location}' sample.txt`

Comment: sorry had typos it's suppose to be the full IP. I modified the information. The location

Comment: The location information exist for every record. It's the IP or hostname of the system. When I run the awk command I get this output...awk: cmd. line:1: ^Index/ {index=$3} /^Type/ {type=$3} /Location/ {location="unclear requirement"} /Revision/ { print index, type, location}
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error

Comment: Typos too: `awk '/^Index/ {ind=$3} /^Type/ {type=$3} /Location/ {location="unclear requirement"} /Revision/ { print ind type location}' sample.txt`

Comment: This just replies with "unclear requirement" for each line item. I just want to capture each section of the file into a set of variables.

Comment: That grep command isn't a good starting point, please post sample input (contents of `sample.txt` not the output of running grep on sample.txt) and the **exact** expected output given that input (not just part of the output, all of the output) so we can help you. You said `I would like to do more grep/sed` but that's almost always the wrong approach and you should use awk instead of a multi-command pipe of greps and seds.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this **might** be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r rec; do
     echo sql -update .... "$rec"
done < <(
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            FS = "[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"
            OFS = ","
        }
        $1 ~ /^(Index|Type|Location)/ {
            rec = rec sep $2
            sep = OFS
        }
        !NF {
            print rec
            rec = sep = ""
        }
        END {
            print rec
        }
    ' "${@:--}"
)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh sample.txt
sql -update .... 11,Client, Disk Proxy Client,192.1680.11
sql -update .... 12,Client,192.1680.12
sql -update .... 56,Client,10.0.10.112
```

or if you really want 3 separate shell variables for some reason then:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=':' read -r index type location; do
     echo sql -update .... "$index,$type,$location"
done < <(
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            FS = "[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"
            OFS = ":"
        }
        $1 ~ /^(Index|Type|Location)/ {
            rec = rec sep $2
            sep = OFS
        }
        !NF {
            print rec
            rec = sep = ""
        }
        END {
            print rec
        }
    ' "${@:--}"
)
```

Remove the `echo` and fix the sql query if I'm right, otherwise update your question with more complete requirements and more truly representative sample input/output.

Note that the above is directly using sample.txt as input, not the output of your existing grep command, we're no longer using that.

Comment: Nice and clean. By the way I think it is worth noting that the right hand side values in the input should not contain `:` otherwise they will be truncated.

Comment: @Dzienny yeah, I was going to accommodate that but didn't want to put much effort into an answer until the OP provides sample input/output.

Comment: Thanks for detail response. I get this error message. /tst.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/tst.sh: line 5: `done < <('

Comment: Are you sure you're running `bash` using the shebang in my script? What does `$SHELL --version` output?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: I figured out the bash issue now. Re-trying...

Comment: I still get this output. sql -update .... ,,::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Comment: The either you copy/pasted my script wrong, or the input you're testing with now doesn't look like the sample input you provided, or your awk or bash are broken. Are you testing using the input from your question or something else? As you can see in my answer, my script will produce the posted expected output from the posted sample input.

Answer (score 0):

If `sed` is an option and your expected output is correct (lower case as well as `client` being chopped at the `,`), you can try this;

```
$ sed '/Up/{N;d};s/\([[:alnum:]]\+\)[^[:alnum:]]*\([^,]*\).*/\L\1=\2/' file
index=11
type=client
location=192.1680.11

index=12
type=client
location=192.1680.12

index=56
type=client
location=10.0.10.112
```

Comment: For each "client entry", I would like to pass the output as a variable for re-use. I believe this is just editing the text.

Comment: @nyitguy text-processing tools like grep, sed, and awk read text in and print [modified] text out, so I think we're all struggling to understand what you mean by `I would like to pass the output as a variable for re-use`. If you want to read the output of a command into a variable then you have to write the shell code to do that, but that's something separate from manipulating text and so separate from whatever sed, grep, or awk command(s) you use to transform your text from the input format to the output format.